# How can I fix this error when using R to reply to a tweet?

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth, rtweet

I am trying to respond to a tweet using `rtweet` and am getting an error.

```
$errors[[1]]$message
[1] "You attempted to reply to a Tweet that is deleted or not visible to you."
```

I know that the tweet is not deleted or invisible because it is my tweet.

Here is the picture of the code and error:

[image: Picture of the code and error]

Thanks in advance

Edit: Code Added and changed the variable names and string text to make more sense

```
tweetid<-1348291478620155905
post_tweet("This is a test tweet", in_reply_to_status_id = tweetid, auto_populate_reply_metadata = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Comment: is the value of `test` a string? please share this as text so others can read and search for it.

Comment: Added in the code and made it a little more clear